# Search for file using partial name then copy file to another location

Tags: vba

Hi I have been having a go at trying to make this work but its been a while since I have used VBA,
can anybody shine any light on the below? Any help is greatly appreciated
the getfolder line doesnt seem to be working for me.

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'use Const for fixed values
Const SRC_PATH As String = "C:\Users\oliver\Servicing - Job Sheets"
Const DEST_PATH As String = "C:\Users\oliver\Servicing Client Files\Wasdell\Job Sheets"

```
Dim fname As Variant

fname = Dir(SRC_PATH & "Wasdell Europe*")

If Len(fname) > 0 Then
    FileCopy SRC_PATH & fname, DEST_PATH & fname
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Put a "\" on the end of both `myPath` and `DestFile`   Also you seem to be calling Dir() twice?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for looking at this, the code seems to work without any errors however the task isn't being executed. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Ah my mistake it does work, however the problem is I have files named SCL123456 - Wasdell Europe. Is it possible to search for just the "Wasdell Europe" part then copy the file?

Comment: See update to my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'use Const for fixed values 
    Const SRC_PATH As String = "C:\Users\oliver\Servicing - Job Sheets\"
    Const DEST_PATH As String = "C:\Users\oliver\Servicing Client Files\Wasdell\Job Sheets\"

    Dim fname As Variant
    
    fname = Dir(SRC_PATH & "*Wasdell Europe*") '<< anywhere in file name
    
    If Len(fname) > 0 Then
        FileCopy SRC_PATH & fname, DEST_PATH & fname
    End If

End Sub
```